# Record Type limitation per profile

Tags: record-type

I have a global action that create a Case using a specific record type. However, I don't want to let this record type available for Admin profile.
Is there a way to authorize a record type only for a global action for a specific profil ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want Admin to access this global action as well as case recordtype then following configurations needs to be done.

1. In the System Admin profile, remove the recordtype assignment.
2. Create a separate Publisher Layout for non-admin user, add the global action in the layout and assign the page layout to non-admin profiles.

This way, admin will be see the action from layout.

Comment: I want let admin see the global action defined with the record type wich I removed from the admin profile...

Comment: In this situation, whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: If the record type is not allowed for admin, I could not create my Case record type using the global action button

Comment: Then why you need this action to be available for admin? You can show this action in the page layout but it is of not use to Admin

Comment: I have 2 object : Case and Request, and my previous task was everytime I create a new Request, a new Case is created using a specific record type. My global action create a new Case with this specific record type. But, I don't want to autorize admin to create directy a Case with the possibility to choose this specific record type.

Hope you followed me ahahah
Thanks !